# Explain how plimpton and lawton’s experiment worked

Tags: electric-fields

If charge is sent to the outside sphere through a battery, won't it induce all the charge from the inside sphere to flow to the outside sphere?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charge is only on the surface of the sphere due to repulsion of the charge from the inside of a sphere, so no charges flow into the inner sphere. This results in 0 electric field everywhere inside the conductor resulting in no induced charge in the inner shell which means no current from the inner to outer shell